# Transfer the ownerhsip of views and tables from postgres superuser to another user using psql in a script

Tags: bash, postgresql, postgresql-10

I want to change the ownership of a database from postgres to a different user using a bash script.

I found thru a link in stackoverflow the following command:

```
# Change owner of tables and views.
for tbl in $(pgexec "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='$schema';" $database) \
           $(pgexec "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.views WHERE table_schema='$schema';" $database)
do
        pgexec "ALTER TABLE \"$schema\".\"$tbl\" OWNER TO $role;" $database 
    done
```

I call the command using the following function:

```
function  pgexec() {
        local cmd=$1
        local database=$2 
        sudo -u postgres psql -d $database --record-separator=\0 -c $cmd
```

I get the following error:

```
 relation public.table_name doesn't exist
```

The `pgexec` I tested with multiple other sql queries and is working.

Answer (score 1):

First, tables **and** views are listed in `information_schema.tables` so you would be altering the views *twice* since you are also querying `information_schema.views`

You could easily achieve this in SQL without the aid of the shell (except to execute it). Something like this:

```
/* Create a function as you would likely reuse this action */
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.set_owner (in_schema TEXT, in_role TEXT)
RETURNS VOID
AS $$

DECLARE object_name TEXT;

BEGIN

    FOR object_name IN (
        SELECT
            table_schema || '.' || table_name AS object_name
        FROM
            information_schema.tables
        WHERE
            schema = in_schema
        )
    LOOP
        EXECUTE FORMAT('ALTER TABLE %s OWNER TO %s', object_name, in_role);
    END LOOP;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL VOLATILE;
```

Call it like `SELECT public.set_owner('public', 'tbl_owner');`

Comment: I need to work with bash because I'm working on an automation script.where you get variables from input

Comment: You can call the function from bash, can you not? It accepts the variables/parameters you get from input.